# How to loop through elements in an xml document using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, altova

I am using XSLT to loop through an XML document.

The root node of the document is called **movies** and it can contain one or more **movie** elements. However these **movie** elements contain single elements except for the **actor** element. How can you loop through to display more than one actor? I am already using `<xsl:for-each>` to loop throught each **movie**.
Here is the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="/movies">

<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylecss.css" />
        <title>My Movies Collection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Use for each loop to extract all child nodes and their information-->

    <xsl:for-each select="/movies/movie">
    <!--Add title as well as year-->
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="title" />
        <xsl:text> ( </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@year" />
        <xsl:text> ) </xsl:text>

        </h1>
        <p>
        <img>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="poster" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
        <span id="details">

        <xsl:text>Review: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@review" />
        <xsl:text>, Type: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@type" />
        <br></br>

        <xsl:text>Producer: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="producer" /> 
        <br/>

        <xsl:text>Actor: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="actor"/> <br/>

        <xsl:text>Director: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="director" /><br/>
        <br/>


<i>         <xsl:text>Comments: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="comments" /> </i>



        </span>
        </p>

    </xsl:for-each>

    </body>

</html>



</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xml document itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xslt" ?>
<movies>
  <movie type="comedy" rating="PG" review="4" year="1997">
  <title>How To Be A Player</title>
  <writer>Mark Brown</writer>
  <producer>Todd R. Baker</producer>
  <director>Russell Simmons</director>
  <actor>Bill Bellamy</actor>
  <actor>Mari Morrow</actor>
  <poster>img/htbap.jpeg</poster>
  <comments>Promotes polygamy</comments>  
  </movie>


  <movie type="comedy" rating="PG" review="5" year="2010">
  <title>Grown Ups</title>
  <writer>Adam Sandler</writer>
  <producer>Jack Giarraputo</producer>
  <director>Fred Wolf</director>
  <actor>Chris Rock</actor>
  <actor>Rob Schneider</actor>
  <poster>img/gu.jpeg</poster>
  <comments>Funny stuff</comments>  
  </movie>

 <movie type="drama" rating="PG" review="5" year="2010">
  <title>The Social Network</title>
  <writer>Dana Brunetti</writer>
  <producer>Scott Rudin</producer>
  <director>David Fincher</director>
  <actor>Jesse Eisenberg</actor>
  <actor>Justin Timberlake</actor>
  <poster>img/sn.jpeg</poster>
  <comments>So innovative</comments>  
  </movie>

  <movie type="comedy" rating="PG" review="5" year="2012">
        <title>Project X</title>
        <writer>Nima Nourizadeh</writer>
        <producer>Todd Phillips</producer>
        <director>Nima Nourizadeh</director>
        <actor>Thomas Mann</actor>
        <actor>Oliver Cooper</actor>
        <poster>img/px.jpeg</poster>
        <comments>Best party to ever</comments>
    </movie> 

</movies>
```

Comment: Could you post your xml and xsl, please?

Comment: Your question is still lacking information. Please add your input XML, your actual output HTML and the HTML output you _expect_.

Comment: @FabianMebus added the xml & xslt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason why you can nest an `xsl:for-each` within another one. So you could replace `<xsl:value-of select="actor"/>`, which just outputs the text of the first actor, with this

```
 <xsl:for-each select="actor">
     <xsl:value-of select="." /><br />
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Note that the xpath expression in the `select` is a relative expression; it is relative to the `movie` node you are currently positioned on, and so will select all `actor` elements that are child elements of it. (This also means your current `<xsl:for-each select="/movies/movie">` can actually be just `<xsl:for-each select="movie">`)

Having said that, in XSLT it is often better to make use of a template based solution, rather than using `xsl:for-each` as then you could potentially re-use templates, for example if you had multiple writers, or directors too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/movies">
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylecss.css" />
        <title>My Movies Collection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="movie" />
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
    <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        <xsl:text> ( </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@year" /><xsl:text> ) </xsl:text>
    </h1>
    <p>
        <img src="{poster}"/>
        <span id="details">
            <xsl:text>Review: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@review" />
            <xsl:text>, Type: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@type" />
            <br></br>

            <xsl:text>Producer: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="producer" />
            <br/>

            <xsl:text>Actor: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="actor" />
            <br/>

            <xsl:text>Director: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="director" />
            <br/>

            <i>         
                <xsl:text>Comments: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="comments" />
            </i>
        </span>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> <br/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note the use of Attribute Value Templates in creating the src of the `img` element

```
<img src="{poster}"/>
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

Comment: the dot `.` saves my day! - `<xsl:value-of select="." />`

Answer (score 4):

@Tim C: Really good answer, +1 for that! But just an additional `template` for the *actor* node would do the job as well, right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/movies">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylecss.css"/>
                <title>My Movies Collection</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <!-- Use for each loop to extract all child nodes and their information-->

                <xsl:for-each select="/movies/movie">
                    <!--Add title as well as year-->
                    <h1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                        <xsl:text> ( </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@year"/>
                        <xsl:text> ) </xsl:text>
                    </h1>

                    <p>
                        <img>
                            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                <xsl:value-of select="poster"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </img>
                        <span id="details">
                            <xsl:text>Review: </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@review"/>
                            <xsl:text>, Type: </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
                            <br></br>
                            <xsl:text>Producer: </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="producer"/>
                            <br/>
                            <xsl:text>Actor: </xsl:text>
                            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="actor"/> -->

                            <!-- apply the 'actor' node -->
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="actor"/>

                            <br/>
                            <xsl:text>Director: </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="director"/>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <i>
                                <xsl:text>Comments: </xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="comments"/>
                            </i>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- the additional actor template -->
    <xsl:template match="actor">
        <!-- get the value -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <!-- set a comma and a whitespace if it is not the last 'actor' node -->
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It would do the job, but as Tim has already explained is his answer, XSLT is a functional programming language where templates are preferred over procedural `for-each` constructs in many situations. This is one of them.